# MessageQueue Name and message queue size

Tags: c, linux, posix

I have two more questions.
1. How can I pass the message queue name as a command line argument? For instance I wrote:

```
char src[50] , dest[50];
strcpy(src , "/");
strcpy(dest , argv[1]); // argv[1] is the name of message queue
strcat(dest , src);
char *msgqueue;
strcpy(msgqueue , dest);
```

However , it gives segmentation fault and when I change as char msgqueue[50] , not valid error emerges.

1. How I can reach the number of elements in a message queue? I tried m_attr.mq_msgsize but I see that it does not give the answer.

I need your help please they are the last steps for completing my homework !

Thank you for all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *msgqueue; //allocate memory and then copy
strcpy(msgqueue , dest);
```

or

```
  msgqueue=strdup(dest);
```

or

As   Joachim Pileborg suggested

if no more modification are needed, just `msgqueue = dest;`

And you want to copy `argv[1]` to message queue and then add "/" at the end.

```
char *msgqueue=malloc(strlen(argv[1])+3); //one for null byte and another one for / for safe use one extra byte

strcpy(msgqueue,argv[1]);
strcat(msgqueue,"/");
```

Comment: Or if no more modification are needed, just `msgqueue = dest;`

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate memory for `msgqueu`. For example

msgqueue = malloc(255);

and somwhere you should release this memory
See about [memory allocation in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

Answer (score 0):

> How I can reach the number of elements in a message queue? I tried m_attr.mq_msgsize but I see that it does not give the answer.

I assume you mean how many messages are currently in the queue.  You use `mq_getattr` for this. You are already using `mq_getattr` in your server but you are looking at a different field.  You want `mq_curmsgs`.

I assume you want to look at this because you want to know exactly how many `mq_receives` to do in your server so that you don't block on a receive for a msg that will never arrive.  This is one way of doing that but it is not fool proof because there is always going to be a race condition between when your server checks how many messages and your client stops writing messages.  There are alternatives (e.g. non-blocking queue for polling, timed receives, and mq_notify) but the simplest for your situation is to just use a separate kind of message that the clients send that announces to the server "I'm done".

Comment: Yes you touched on a good point , my question is exactly what you've said. Thank you!

Comment: @Begumm - You are welcome.  I see you have enough reputation to award points now so you should think about going back through your questions and upvoting whatever answers you thought helpful.

Comment: Sorry I did not properly understand what I should do. How can I up vote an answer?

Comment: @Begumm, it not you.  SO doesn't allow anyone with less than 15 reputation points to up vote - you press the up/down arrow at the side of the answers - so it sometimes happens that a new person asks several questions and gets a some good answers that he can't vote upon until he accumulates enough points.  Now that you have you can give points to whoever you felt helped you, which may or may not include me.  Incidentally, I think you need 125 reputation to down vote.